# Get field based on annotation value

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to get the field based on the annotation value for the field?

I got this annotation class:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation{
String value();
}
```

And the class that uses the annotation:

```
@MyAnnotation("fieldA")
public String a;

@MyAnnotation("FieldB")
public String b;

@MyAnnotation("FieldC")
public String c;
```

Now I want to access the string b without knowing the field name and only the annotation value. Is this possible? I know I can get all the declared fields and their annotations and loop through them but was hoping I could avoid that.

Comment: Just iterate over all fields. For each field get its annotation. And then check if the annotation contains the value you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that, but was hoping there was some way of just getting a list of all the annotation values and based on those I could access a field

Comment: Use can use some Reflection Lib, that abstracts away your problem. Then you can do that using 1 line of code. Some lib like this: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections